# How to trigger a creation of a SharePoint Online site collection with the creation of a new user in Keycloak

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I need to know how I can trigger the creation of a new SharePoint Online site collection with an external identity provider in my case KeyCloak.

As soon as a new user has been created and a certain flag is set. Then is should trigger the generation of a new SharePoint Online site collection.

I don't really know where to start. Maybe I can use the endpoint of KeyCloak.

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You can create new SharePoint Online sites programmatically using either the Microsoft Graph APIs or the SharePoint APIs. More information on how to utilise these APIs can be found here:

[Working with SharePoint sites in Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[SharePoint .NET Server, CSOM, JSOM, and REST API index](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index)

Additionally, there is [PnP.PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/), [PnP Framework](https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework) and [PnP Core SDK](https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore), which are open source projects that are very useful for utilising SharePoint and Microsoft 365.

I imagine you will need to utilise some sort of event receiver in Keycloak and then call one of these Microsoft APIs or your own custom application e.g. Power Automate flow, Azure Function etc to then create the SharePoint site.